# How I can define the name of the file with respect to the chart symbol?

Tags: mql5, metatrader5

I have tried the following and got the error:

```
#define filename  _Symbol+"_Trade_reatime.csv";

input string forecast_fetch=filename;
```

Error got is:

```
'+' - constant expected Trade_Real_Time.mq5     87      29
```

Please let me know what I can do to have this sort of file name. My signal vary with respect to the symbol on chart. Hence, I need to have the file name with respect to chart to avoid typing file name every time. Please let me know the way out.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the define you did, but that is not very handy.
`#define filename  (_Symbol+"_Trade_reatime.csv")` is better because you can substitute your `filename` in any function you need.
The piece of code you gave can be compiled, please edit your post providing MCVE and indicate the line #87 which causes the problem to go futher.

Comment: The line number is the place where I have written the `#define`

Comment: I am still getting the same error after assign it to the `input string forecast_fetch=filename;`

Comment: Add brackets as in my example

Comment: I have added the brackets as you specify. But got the same error. Amigo, I have tried many things but I guess that is not possible , what I guess.

Comment: Do not see any problems here https://gyazo.com/c19144bfa5cab7d82ae8890ea5727eff The problem is that you want to assign that value to input variable (so it is not a constant). If you remove `input` modifier, it works. And the error is at the line of `input string...` not when you define

Comment: May be but if I wanted to assign to input variable as per the chart, then what I can do?

Comment: Only constant expressing. If I were you, I would have `input string forecast_fetch="_Trade_reatime.csv";` then `#define filename  (_Symbol+forecast_fetch)` in order to use sth like `int handle=FileOpen(filename,FILE_WRITE|FILE_CSV);`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Daniel. But this was not something I expected. It is similar that I do not define the `input` variable and directly use the `string` variable`. One and the same thing. Anyways Thanks Amigo. I cannot accept the answer but I can upvote it.